# How to read images from our system folder to jupyter notebook python file

Tags: pandas, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, data-science

I have nine pictures inside a folder . I have to just read all the images in python for making a opencv model .
I want to read the all images at the same time in my .py notebook for do operations on the images .
please help

Answer (score 0):

**To read the image using OpenCV I have defined load_images_from_folder function which takes a path where images are stored as an input parameter
, In the next step cv2.imread function read all files in a folder and append them to images =[] list then return images list.**

```
import os

def load_images_from_folder(foldername):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(foldername):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(foldername,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images
img_list=load_images_from_folder("photos")
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided. See [answer].